# apache log files - getting data trimmed and filtered

Tags: sql-server, apache, logging

I'm looking to trim down an apache log file - at the moment it currently has around 3m rows (as it includes things like image and video files being loaded, basically any url with .jpg) however when doing a straight dump into sql server and doing various querying there to remove these as well as removing duplicates I can get this down to 100k rows and from there export to sql server and link to various other sources.

What i am looking at trying to get is say the below:

1.2.3.4   15/04/2016:10:20:30 [test_url]/testpage 200

1.2.3.4   15/04/2016:10:25:30 [test_url]/testproduct 200

From the following from the log file:

%h %t \"%r\" %>s

1.2.3.4   [15/Apr/2016:10:20:30 +0000] GET [test_url]/testpage HTTP/1.1 200

1.2.3.4   [15/Apr/2016:10:20:30 +0000] GET [test_url]/testpage HTTP/1.1 200

1.2.3.4   [15/Apr/2016:10:20:30 +0000] GET [test_url]/testimage.jpg HTTP/1.1 200

1.2.3.4   [15/Apr/2016:10:25:30 +0000] GET [test_url]/testproduct HTTP/1.1 200

Also I want to remove any duplicates (so the second row in the above is removed as it is a duplicate and the third is gone as it is a .jpg) - does anyone have an idea of what code would work with this (if it is indeed feasible).

Quite easy to do this if all the data is dumped in SQL server but need to trim the dataset at source to help preserve server space. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to talk about the Apache's access_log you had to set the CustomLog-directive for access_log at some point. Just add `env=!dontlog` at the end of the line, e.g.:

```
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combined env=!dontlog
```

Then define as many rules as you want to exclude specific requests:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr 10.11.12.13 dontlog
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/images/.*" dontlog
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.(mpeg|mp4|jpe?g|png|gif)" dontlog
SetEnvIf User-Agent Robot dontlog
```

etc...be creative, myb a read of the [according Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html) will help :)

Comment: Thanks, also one other thing, is it possible to remove parts of a uri string in this process - e.g. [testurl]/testpage/testpage.html?promocode=test to [testurl]/testpage

Comment: Not if you use `%U` to log the URI or pretty much any other standard variable. But you can always define an environment variable and log that instead to create your unique and own logformat ;) In that case you would `SetEnvIf` based on URIs as well, but set the variable to a specific value, e.g. the stripped version of your URI/query string. I'd recommend to read this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html  and the above link on `SetEnvIf` to get an idea of how to achieve that.